# Rendering custom "Integrate with Google" button - gapi.additnow

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

The render method of gapi.additnow takes as the second parameter an key-value pair object.

As in the following example:

```
gapi.additnow.render(
    "el-id",
    {"param1": "value_of_param1", "param2": "value_of_param2"}
)
```

Where can I find the list of available parameters to use.

I'm aiming on using the params to customize the "Integrate" button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you can get a full list, but the docs show "width" and "theme" as params in the example code:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button#additnow-tag-attributes

Comment: Link broken... 404